# How to hide/remove guid from sharepoint search result page?

Tags: document, enterprise-search, guid

In sharepoint search result page, while searching for a document, document guid is showing up in the result along with the document name. Is there any way to hide or remove the guid of the document in the search result page?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "Crawl Rules" on your Search Service Application to exclude the URLs based on the pattern you want to remove.  For instance * { * - * - * - * - * } * (without the spaces) would exclude URLs that have a format like a GUID in them.

Comment: GUID is not coming in the URL..its is showing up in the result page. Each document is tagged with enterprise tag..so when u search for a document, it shows up like this
Document Name
tag1:23408A-214089-Uh34252;tag2:89741-io2431234-342j23...

So i need to remove these guids and display only tag name